# Adding a background image to a single table cell

Tags: html, css, joomla

Hello I was wondering if it's possible to add a background image to a single table cell? If you look at the image I have below I would like the green background image I have to be in those cells.

[image: example image]

My code for the table is,

```
<table class="TFtable" style="height: 448px;" width="1007">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #000000;">
<p><span style="font-size: 200%; color: #749d36;">    Pricing</span></p>
<p><span style="font-size: 200%;">     Structure</span></p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p><span style="font-size: medium;">Professional</span></p>
<p><span style="font-size: medium;">Resume</span></p>
<br /><br />
<p><span style="font-size: xx-large; color: #749d36;">$199</span></p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>Managerial</p>
<p>Resume</p>
<p>$299</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p><span style="font-size: medium;">Executive</span></p>
<p><span style="font-size: medium;">Resume</span></p>
<br /><br />
<p><span style="font-size: xx-large; color: #749d36;">$399</span></p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>C-Suite</p>
<p>Resume</p>
<p>$499</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Resume Specs</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: small;">2-3 pg resume</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">4-5 pg resume</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>+ cover sheet and</p>
<p>graphics</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">+ standalone bio pg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Phone Interview</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Draft To Approve</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Template Options</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"> </td>
<td style="text-align: center;"> </td>
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><br /><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/greentick.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Extras</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"> </td>
<td style="text-align: center;"> </td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>+ free LinkedIn</p>
<p>profile</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>+ free LinkedIn</p>
<p>profile</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Delivery</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>.docx &amp; .pdf</p>
<p>versions</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>.docx &amp; .pdf</p>
<p>versions</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>.docx &amp; .pdf</p>
<p>versions</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>.docx &amp; .pdf</p>
<p>versions</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Cover Letter</span></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><br />+ $50<br /><br /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><br />+ $50<br /><br /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><br />+ $50<br /><br /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><br />+ $50<br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #000000; text-align: center;">
<p>If you're not sure where</p>
<p>your job would fit, please</p>
<p>get in touch to discuss </p>
<p>your requirements.</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>Vocations (such as</p>
<p>Teaching &amp; Nursing)</p>
<p>Early Career Professionals</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>Managers and Senior</p>
<p>Professionals (Lawyers,</p>
<p>Medical Doctors), BDMs,</p>
<p>Consultants...</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>Senior Managers and Exec</p>
<p>Directors (Operations</p>
<p>Managers, GMs, Heads of</p>
<p>Department</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>CEOs, CFOs, COOs, CIOs,</p>
<p>Managing Directors, Board</p>
<p>Members &amp; Non-Execs,</p>
<p>Practice Directors &amp; Principals</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
```

Comment: Ugh, so many inline styles...

Comment: Don't know any other way to do it sorry about that. Could you help me with a background image inside a single table cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using CSS:

First you will need to create an ID for the table cell that you wish to have an image as the background.

After this, you will need to do this in CSS:

```
#tableCellWithBackground {
    background-image: url("<The location of your image in your webspace, or the url of the image.");
}
```

This should work, tell me if there is a bug or something wrong.

Comment: I would recommend a class instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I go to create an ID for the table cell the text within that cell leaves the table. Are you able to tell me the html code for inside the table that i should be using?

Answer (score 6):

You could try:

```
<td style="background-image: url(PATH/TO/IMAGE);">
```

If you absolutely have to do it inline.

However using CSS would be way cleaner. Something like:

HTML:

```
<td class="green_background"></td>
```

CSS:

```
.green_background {
   background-image: url(PATH/TO/IMAGE.JPG);
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it shows both the HTML and the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

All done. Here you go. See the JSfiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanmpower/qkvm8tqg/). I added the green background to "Managerial Resume" for you. Since you're doing all the CSS inline you need to add `background-image: url('http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/green/green-04.jpg')` to the `<td>` `<style>` tag.